# Operation `users.findOneAndUpdate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find and update a document from a mongodb database but I am facing this error over and over again

**The error**

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOneAndUpdate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Development\discord-bot\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:148:23)
```

**What I haved tried ?**

I have used using async/await for the mongodb connection and still it doesnt work

**Code**

`index.js`

```js
client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity(`Mind Meld`, {
        type: "PLAYING",
    });
    await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
        try {
            console.log('Connected to mongo!!');
        }
        finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });
});
```

`database/mongo.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
        keepAlive: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
        .then(x => {
            console.log(
                `Connected to Mongo! Database name: "${x.connections[0].name}"`,
            );
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err);
        });
    return mongoose;
};
```

The command

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const User = require('../../../api/database/schemas/user')
const { error, success } = require('../../utils/colors')

module.exports = {
    name: 'lobby',
    aliases: ['lobby'],

    execute(message, args) {
        User.findOneAndUpdate({ discordId: message.author.id }, { $set: { playing: true } }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                message.reply("done!")
            }
        })
    },
};
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines about using Promises, callbacks and async-await syntax with MongoDB NodeJS.: [Promises and Callbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/).

Comment: @prasad_, Hey, could you actually help me out instead of link documentation. I have read through that documentation already

Comment: It is possible you are using promises and async-await together - you need to use one or the other.

Comment: @prasad_Thanks, I have resolved the issue